# Why are the Permutation Functions of STL not working here?

Tags: c++, stl, permutation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {2, 1, 3};
    auto printArray = [&a]() -> void
    {
        for (const auto& e : a) std::cout << " " << e;
        std::cout << "\n";
    };

    // My doubts are here
    while (std::prev_permutation(a, a + 3)) printArray();
    while (std::next_permutation(a, a + 3)) printArray();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

1 3 2

1 2 3

***But I thought the output would be:***

1 3 2

1 2 3

1 3 2

2 1 3

2 3 1

3 1 2

3 2 1

Seems like the call to `next_permutation` never happens here, but why?

Comment: Because when `std::prev_permutation` returns false, it also sets `a` to the "last" permutation. You need to call `std::next_permutation` once between the loops to set `a` back to the "first" permutation.

Comment: That worked @HolyBlackCat I wonder if that reflects the non-intuitive design of these standard functions?

Comment: A bad workman blames his tools

Comment: @ThomasSablik Isn't there any other way to set that first/last state of `a`?

Comment: `std::sort` sets the container to the first state.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Even if `std::sort` sets the flag, it would consume extra time to sort the container which is not my intention. Why are these flags complicating the use of this function? Isn't there a public function to just alter the state of these flags in STL?

Comment: What flags are you talking about? You asked how to set the first state. The permutation functions produce permutations in lexicographical order (with respect to operator<) and the first or "lowest" lexicographical order is sorted.

Comment: You should read [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to understand how it works. There are no flags. You can pass your own `comp` function, e.g. you could pass a counter as `comp` function.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, by flags I mean the first/last state of the container mentioned by @HolyBlackCat. The suggested solution works but it makes an extra call to `next_permutation` just to alter the first/last state of the container. Isn't there a better readable way to do that?

Comment: As I said you can pass your own `comp` function. There you can specify the "flags". You could pass the initial state and compare in each permutation step

Comment: @ThomasSablik that seems interesting. Could you post an answer elaborating that point? I didn't quite get it because I'm fairly new to STL.

Comment: Sorry, there is no `std::is_this_already_the_last_permutation` function. I guess you could call `std:is_sorted` and pass `std::greater` as the comparison to see if it's in the last state. That seems very wasteful to do inside every call of the permutation function(s) instead of just letting the state wrap around the last time and returning `false`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I see... but isn't that the last permutation only for prev_permutation? For next_permutation it should have been the first permutation, isn't it?

Comment: Just think of each call stepping through the ordered list of permutations in ascending or descending order. From the last or greatest state `std::next_permitation` wraps around to the first or lowest state (and returns `false`). `std::prev_permutation` does the same but in the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) the array after the last call to `std::prev_permutation`:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> a {2, 1, 3};

    using std::begin; using std::end;

    while (std::prev_permutation(begin(a), end(a))) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    std::reverse(begin(a), end(a));
    assert(std::is_sorted(begin(a), end(a)));
    while (std::next_permutation(begin(a), end(a))) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/436223c6c7d31d30)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a compare function. In this example I passed a compare function containing a counter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> a = {2, 1, 3};
    auto printArray = [&a]() -> void
    {
        for (const auto& e : a) std::cout << " " << e;
        std::cout << "\n";
    };

    // My doubts are here
    while (std::prev_permutation(std::begin(a), std::end(a))) printArray();
    while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](const auto &, const auto &) {
        static std::size_t i = 2 * 6 + 1;
        if (i != 0) --i;
        return i != 0;
    })) printArray();

    return 0;
}
```

There are two comparisons per permutation.